# IE11 pdf as iframe src starts download of pdf

Tags: html, pdf, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to embed a PDF file to my bootstrap page and trying to get it to work for IE11.

Now i'm running this simpel code:

```
<div id="pdf">
   <iframe src="/Content/Test.pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
        <p>It appears your web browser doesn't support iframes.</p>
   </iframe>
</div>
```

However when i load the page i get the following dialog.

> do you want to open or save

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be a browser-issue. Sort of protection.